# RedirectToAction not passing parameters MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an action that takes list of model items and delete them, My question is that , why the parameters not getting passed

```
public ActionResult DeleteMultiple(IEnumerable<QAModel> model)
    {
        _qaService.DeleteMultiple(model);
        long subscriptionId = model.First().SubscriptionId; //value is available here 
        long languageId = model.First().LanguageId;         //value is available here
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { SubscriptionId =subscriptionId, LanguageId =languageId,Message="Data deleted successfully ."});

    }
```

//redirection happens but the value getting null inside Index method.

```
   public ActionResult Index(int? SubscriptionId,int? LanguageId,string Message)
    {



    }
```

what am i doing wrong can any one please help me for this stuff.

Comment: Is the redirect to Index only from `DeleteMultiple` ? are you sure you're not redirecting to Index from somewhere else ?

Comment: Parameter type is System.Int32 in Index() method, but you are passing System.Int64?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov , no there are more then one methods that redirects to the action index

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have tried with System.Int32  too but yet not getting values inside Index

Comment: When you're debugging and your break point is hit, are you sure it's been hit by `DeleteMultiple` or by some other method ?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov yes it being hit but without values

Comment: Put your data in TempData and retrive it in Index action and see temp data is empty or not.

Comment: @mo.esmp let me try it.

Answer (score 1):

RedirectToAction returns a 302 to the browser which causes another GET request from the browser, so your data is not retained.

If you want to call another method just call the method and avoid the round trip to the browser.

```
return Index(...)
```

Comment: thanx but i have tried this one too but when i am doing return Index(...) the Index method called two times first with the parameters and second time without the parameters

Answer (score -1):

Try using Route Value Dictionary [RouteValueDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) in the [RedirectToAction()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492939%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) Method

**C# CODE**

```
public ActionResult DeleteMultiple(IEnumerable<QAModel> model)
    {
        _qaService.DeleteMultiple(model);
        long subscriptionId = model.First().SubscriptionId; //value is available here 
        long languageId = model.First().LanguageId;         //value is available here
        return RedirectToAction("Index",new RouteValueDictionary {{"SubscriptionId",subscriptionId},{"LanguageId",languageId},{"Message","Data deleted successfully ."}, } );

    }
```

Hope it may help you, Have a nice day.